# React Native App Atom IDE error not allowing to create config folder

Tags: macos, react-native, expo, atom-editor, hyper

I keep getting this error message when I try to create a "config" folder for my Firebase API code inside Atom and even in Visual Studio Code.

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users//Documents/ReactNativeProjects/react-firebase-app/config'

I've been trying to fix this error the entire day and I'm struggling to find a solution.

someone, please help me.

I'm on MacOs: 10.15.3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer hours later, had to reset permissions inside the app folder.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538